# mod_rewrite chaining?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a bootstrap php file that I am routing all requests through:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Say I have a url like /books/moby-dick, but I need the URL to pass to the index file like /books/detail/moby-dick. Is there a way to "rewrite" /books/moby-dick to /books/detail/moby-dick before the last RewriteRule? I thought the Chain [C] flag would do it but I end up with "books/detail/moby-dick/moby-dick". Here's where I'm currently stuck:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ books/detail/$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried that **[C] flag** in my Apache 2.4 setup and I just got 
**_Syntax error on line ... RewriteCond: unknown flag 'C'_**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any rewrites that you perform will automatically flow down to subsequent rules in your rule set provided that you don't cause the process to end/restart with the `L` (which typically restarts when used in `.htaccess`) or `N` flag. You could remove the chaining and it would still work, although in that case you'd have to condition the second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ books/detail/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Note that if you *do* chain the rules together, if the request path does not match the first rule, the request won't be redirected to the bootstrap file.

None of that is the cause of the actual problem though. What happens is that Apache has decided that the request has path info (for reasons I'll have to look into), and after your rewrite it automatically appends that to the result. The supposed "path info" is `/moby-dick`, which is why it ends up appearing twice.

Luckily, since we didn't want it in the first place, we can discard it with the [`DPI` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Keeping the above points in mind, the following will redirect a request to `books/moby-dick` to `index.php?query=books/detail/moby-dick`:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ books/detail/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

(I made the assumption you wanted `books/detail/name`, although you also mentioned `books/view/name`)

Comment: DPI looks like what I've been looking for. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess rules (unlike the same rules in httpd.conf) the [L] flag *starts all over at the top*. You probably really want to use the [END] flag (but only later versions of Apache support it). I believe the reason you get your change repeated has nothing to do with the [C] flag, but rather is because that line is being executed twice. (In fact the only thing that saves you from an "infinite loop" is your "-f" test ultimately stops things).

Each modification in a .htaccess file is *always* "passed on" to the next line (there are no flags to either enable or disable this behavior). The little-used [C] flag seems to mainly be useful for nested conditionals and for very slight simplification of some awkward if-then-else structures, neither of which you're doing in the example. That's why I don't understand that you need the [C] flag at all.

The standard technique to avoid massive looping and repeating problems in older .htaccess files is to add a bit of boilerplate at the top, something like

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^[ /]*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```